# How complete is Texpad on the iPad

Tags: ipad, texpad

For 7.99 Euro I can purchase [Texpad](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/texpad-latex-editor/id550419159?mt=8) in the Apple store. It is just 11.4 MB, so it won't be as complete as my TeX Live 2012. Has anyone experience, how complete it is? Is it just the standard classes or could I prepare my Beamer slides with it?

Comment: You should have a look at these blog entries : http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/10/i-tex-therefore-ipad/ and the following http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2012/09/i-tex-therefore-ipad-reloaded/ I'm not sure it regards exactly the same tex distribution as you are looking for, but it seems it will help you in your quest anyway.

Comment: The idea of having to _purchase_ TeX _for money_ makes me worried :-S

Comment: @tohecz as far as I can see (from the description, I haven't got an ios device) you do not get TeX at all, what you get for the money is an editor and access to a TeX server which will process your documents and return the resulting pdf and/or error report. However there have been many commercial TeX distributions over the years: Textures, pctec, Y&Ytex etc, so charging for a tex distribution wouldn't be that unusual.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, you are right. It's just the editor. I had assumed I would get a (somehow) minimal LaTeX as well.

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen The problem is that "minimal LaTeX" is much larger than that... And David: it still makes me worried...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Texpad developers here.

Since version 1.1 Texpad for iOS has had a built in LaTeX typesetter, no internet connection required.  Most commonly used LaTeX packages are now included, and we expand the distribution with every update (9 updates in the past three months), and it is now so good that one user edits LaTeX on his Mac and typesets on his iPhone because the distribution is leaner, simpler and faster.

PGF drivers are underway right now and the update with local TikZ/Beamer typesetting should be ready for download in Feburary.

In addition to the onboard typesetter, we still provide free cloud typesetting servers with the entirety of TexLive 2012 installed. If you have any further questions, email us at support@vallettaventures.com.

**EDIT: update since Texpad 1.5**

In Texpad 1.5 we added PGF drivers, a virtual font system and a **Bundle Manager** (http://support.texpadapp.com/kb/typesetting-ios/latex-bundle-manager-on-texpad-ios).  Now Texpad is able to typeset virtually any TeX font or package with its onboard typesetter.  This includes, but is certainly not limited to, PGF based packages such as Tikz and Beamer.

NB the reason for the small download size is that bundle manager allows you to install only the necessary bundles when needed.  If files are reported missing during a typeset, the relevant bundle will be suggested to you.

Comment: Do you have a list of packages online somewhere?

Comment: It is also not clear how to add packages to the app. I see the folder Texpad-Custom-Packages, but how do I set it up? What if I wanted to put all Tex Live packages in there?http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91054/powerdot-pstricks-for-local-typesetting-mode-in-texpad-ios

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen Texpad's bundle manager will install almost any package for you.  We discuss it here http://support.texpadapp.com/kb/typesetting-ios/what-packages-are-available-with-texpad-on-ios

Comment: @macmadness86 we have answered that fully here http://support.texpadapp.com/kb/typesetting-ios/how-do-i-add-packages-to-texpad-ios, but there is no need to install standard TeXLive packages yourself as the bundle manager will handle that for you

Comment: @VV Texpad, great! Thank you! Your answer is timely as I just noticed the bundle manager today! Kind of hidden for such an important feature! I've installed just about ever bundle but my documents still will not compile with `\usepackage{fontspec}`. Is there a package list for each bundle?

Comment: @macmadness86 You're welcome. Advanced fonts (non-Computer Modern) had a few issues in the first 1.5 release that have now been fixed by 1.5.1 and 1.5.2 updates. Please try again and if you still have problems, please be in touch with us via 'Contact Support' link on http://texpadapp.com . A minimal working example would be very helpful. ('Working' as in working with Texlive on desktop.) Best

Comment: @VVTexpad Are there any plans to add an install-on-demand package manager to Texpad on macOS?