# powerdot/pstricks for local typesetting mode in Texpad iOS?

Tags: pstricks, powerdot, texpad

I use `powerdot` to typeset my presentations. Has anybody got experience with running `powerdot`/PStricks on the local (Ker)TeX environment coming with Texpad (local typesetting mode)? Is this possible, to begin with?

If so, how would I proceed then: Install `powerdot`/PStricks into the Texpad-Custom-Packages dir?

Besides: I use my own `powerdot` styles. In my regular TeX environment, I provide the style files in my working dir. Trying to have my `powerdot` presentation assembled using cloud typesetting, `powerdot` fails in picking up the style files (one `.sty` + some `.ps`) from my project dir. I then tried to store them in the Texpad-Custom-Packages dir; no luck either.

I'd appreciate any hint, both on my local and cloud typesetting issue!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit. You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 3):

Texpad developers here. Sorry for the belated reply.

The problem with PSTricks and other PS-based packages and utils is that Apple's lack of support for PostScript in iOS makes it difficult to support them.

Texpad supports as an alternative tikz, which is modern and works well with Beamer. There's more details on our KnowledgeBase, e.g. http://support.texpadapp.com/kb/typesetting-ios/what-packages-are-available-with-texpad-on-ios

As for the cloud issues, if you're still having issues, may I ask you to send in your specific request by following 'Contact Support' on our website http://texpadapp.com .

Best.