# Jump from pdf line to Tex line on ipad

Tags: texpad, ipad

I've been using Texpad on my iPad.  I like it a lot, but the one absolutely crucial feature it's missing is the ability to jump from a line in the pdf to the corresponding line in the editor.  When using texshop on a desktop computer this is accomplished with right click.

Does this feature exist for any iPad Tex editors?

Comment: Could you elaborate on your installation? Local *.tex, or is the ipad connected to a server, which compiles and sends the rendered PDF back to the ipad?

Comment: @KeksDose it works without an Internet connection, so it's all on my iPad.

Comment: Found this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83066/4736 .

Comment: I don't know about iPad version of TeXPad on iPad, but in the Mac OS X version, Cmd-click jumps from the current location in the `.pdf` to the corresponding location in the `.tex` source.

Answer (score 0):

Simply touch the line in the pdf for one second or two, and a button “synchronise editor” appears, then click it to jump to the Tex line.